# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token error when adding HTML to a JS file for online store

Tags: javascript, shopping-cart

I'm trying to add Javascript to a WordPress site for its shopping cart. I've added the script tag to the header file but it gets hung up at line 75 of the store.js file (below). I tried JSON encoding using advice found [here](https://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/escape/), but that led me down a rabbit hole of other issues so I was hoping to consult someone more experienced in JavaScript before I kept messing with my code. Any advice?

```html
if (document.readyState == 'loading') {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ready);
} else {
    ready();
}

function ready() {
    var removeCartItemButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-danger');
    for (var i = 0; i < removeCartItemButtons.length; i++) {
        var button = removeCartItemButtons[i];
        button.addEventListener('click', removeCartItem);
    }

    var quantityInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input');
    for (var i = 0; i < quantityInputs.length; i++);
  {
        var input = quantityInputs[i];
        input.addEventListener('change', quantityChanged);
    }

    var addToCartButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-button');
    for (var i = 0; i < addToCartButtons.length; i++) {
        var button = addToCartButtons[i];
        button.addEventListener('click', addToCartClicked);
    }

    document.getElementsByClassName('btn-purchase')[0].addEventListener('click', purchaseClicked);
}

function purchaseClicked() {
    alert('Thank you for your purchase');
    var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0];
    while (cartItems.hasChildNodes()) {
        cartItems.removeChild(cartItems.firstChild);
    }
    updateCartTotal();
}

function removeCartItem(event) {
    var buttonClicked = event.target;
    buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
    updateCartTotal();
}

function quantityChanged(event) {
    var input = event.target;
    if (isNaN(input.value) || input.value <= 0)
    {
        input.value = 1;
    }
    updateCartTotal();
}

function addToCartClicked(event) {
    var button = event.target;
    var shopItem = button.parentElement.parentElement;
    var title = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-title')[0].innerText;
    var price = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-price')[0].innerText;
    var imageSrc = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-image')[0].src;
    addItemToCart(title, price, imageSrc);
    updateCartTotal();
}

function addItemToCart(title, price, imageSrc) {
    var cartRow = document.createElement('div');
    cartRow.classList.add('cart-row');
    var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0];
    var cartItemNames = cartItems.getElementsByClassName('cart-item-title');
    for (var i = 0; i < cartItemNames.length; i++) {
        if (cartItemNames[i].innerText == title) {
            alert('This item is already added to the cart');
            return;
        }
    }
    var cartRowContents = 
        "<div class=\"cart-item cart-column\">\n            <img class=\"cart-item-image\" src=\"${imageSrc}\" width=\"100\" height=\"100\">\n            <span class=\"cart-item-title\">${title}<\/span>\n        <\/div>\n        <span class=\"cart-price cart-column\">${price}<\/span>\n        <div class=\"cart-quantity cart-column\">\n            <input class=\"cart-quantity-input\" type=\"number\" value=\"1\">\n            <button class=\"btn btn-danger\" type=\"button\">REMOVE<\/button>\n        <\/div>";
    cartRow.innerHTML = cartRowContents;
    cartItems.append(cartRow);
    cartRow.getElementsByClassName('btn-danger')[0].addEventListener('click', removeCartItem);
    cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')[0].addEventListener('change', quantityChanged);
}

function updateCartTotal() {
    var cartItemContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0];
    var cartRows = cartItemContainer.getElementsByClassName('cart-row');
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < cartRows.length; i++) {
        var cartRow = cartRows[i];
        var priceElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-price')[0];
        var quantityElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')[0];
        var price = parseFloat(priceElement.innerText.replace('$', ''));
        var quantity = quantityElement.value;
        total = total + (price * quantity);
    }
    total = Math.round(total * 100) / 100;
    document.getElementsByClassName('cart-total-price')[0].innerText = '$' + total;
}
```

Comment: Which line is line 75?

Comment: I get no such error from the code as posted.